# Odata with unbound function : The related entity set or singleton cannot be found from the OData path

Tags: c#, odata

I am looking to create an unbound function inside ProductController which return entirely different entity(Not related to Product).

```
[EnableQuery]
public class ProductsController : ODataController
{
        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("InvokeMyUnBoundFunction(Id={id})")]
        public IHttpActionResult InvokeMyUnBoundFunction(int id)
        {
            TestUnBound testObj= new TestUnBound();
            testObj.Name = "Test" + id;
            return Ok(testObj);
        }
}
```

and my webApiConfig is

```
 ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
 builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
 builder.EntitySet<TestUnBound>("TestUnBounds"); //Its not related to Product.
 builder.Function("InvokeMyUnBoundFunction").Returns<TestUnBound>().Parameter<int>("Id");
```

But when I invoked
http://localhost:port/api/odata/InvokeMyUnBoundFunction(Id=1234)
I got an error message like

> "The related entity set or singleton cannot be found from the OData
>   path. The related entity set or singleton is required to serialize the
>   payload."

Am I missed any concepts?

Comment: call: ReturnsFromEntitySet<T>(string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use

```
ReturnsFromEntitySet<TestUnBound>
```

instread of

```
Returns<TestUnBound>
```

Comment: Yes, Its worked. One more quick doubt.
Is it mandatory to add a key in EnitySet? Bcoz here i am using 'TestUnBound' only to return my data.

Comment: Then why not mark it as a complex type and remove the key

Comment: FYI : odata.github.io/WebApi/

Answer (score 1):

In OData v4, change the function declaration to:

```
builder.Function("InvokeMyUnBoundFunction").ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<TestUnBound>().Parameter<int>("Id");
```

instead of `ReturnsFromEntitySet<TestUnBound>` as suggested by answer.